# При авторизации / выполнения метода контроллера , идет два запроса в БД

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Я использую JWT для проверки пользователя. Руководствовался стандартными фильтрами , которые описаны в интернете. Например вот: https://github.com/bseitkazin/spring-jwt-realization/tree/main/src/main/java/com/example/demoauth/configs/jwt

Когда я делаю метод :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "experience", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> addExpRest( @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsImpl  user,
            @RequestBody List<ExperienceDto> experienceDto) {    
 return experienceService.addData(user.user(), experienceDto);
    }
```

То идет два запроса в консоли:

Это первый

```
Hibernate: select  user0_.id as id1_19_, user0_.version a .. 
Hibernate: select roles0_.users as users1_13_0_, roles0_.roles ..
```

плюс еще перед выполнением метода такой же

```
Hibernate: select  user0_.id as id1_19_, user0_.version a .. 
Hibernate: select roles0_.users as users1_13_0_, roles0_.roles ..
```

Потом уже идет разрешение на выполнение метода.

Запрос идет от UserDetailsService с его методом loadUserByUsername

Вопрос: как избежать лишних запросов , чтобы бы при проверке , был только один ?